# how to set Seamless database pool read slave database as default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rubygems, database-replication

I have problem with seamless gem

```
development:
  adapter: jdbcmysql
  database: mydb_development
  username: read_user
  password: abc123
  pool_adapter: jdbcmysql
  port: 3306
  master:
    host: master-db.example.com
    port: 6000
    username: master_user
    password: 567pass
  read_pool:
    - host: read-db-1.example.com
      pool_weight: 2
    - host: read-db-2.example.com
```

it should read for slave right [read-db-1.example.com] ? but it was weird.. it always read to master database [mydb_development] .

do you have any suggestion, how should i do to configure this gem for default read to slave database?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Specify pool_weight=0 in the master configuration

> By default, the master connection will be included in the read pool. If you would like to dedicate this connection only for write operations, you should set the pool weight to zero.

[seam_leass_database_pool plugin](https://github.com/bdurand/seamless_database_pool)